# How to set METEOR_SETTINGS in Heroku in a Dropbox synced app?

Tags: meteor, heroku

My meteor app is being deployed to Heroku via dropbox sync.

I tried setting the METEOR_SETTINGS variable via the dashboard (under Config Vars) to "$(cat settings.json)" but that doesn't seem to work.

What is the correct way to set METEOR_SETTINGS in these circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to copy the ENTIRE contents of the settings.json file into the "METEOR_SETTINGS" config var in Heroku.

```
{"public": {"env": "Production"," etc....
```